# SignalR difference between Context.Request.Cookies and Context.RequestCookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Is there any difference between `Context.Request.Cookies` and `Context.RequestCookies`? Both properties seem to have identical values. It is confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's exactly the same.
The following is the implementation of the RequestCookies property of Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubCallerContext class:

```
public IDictionary<string, Cookie> RequestCookies
{
    get
    {
        return this.Request.Cookies;
    }
}
```

You can validate that by decompiling the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll.

Actually, since this is open-source, you don't need to decompile, the code can be downloaded from GitHub:  https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/HubCallerContext.cs